# CSS стили, float

Tags: html, css, текст

Здравствуйте, у меня имеется колонна. На ней есть две сетки col-6 (bootstrap).
В этих сетках имеется Текст и картинка. Когда я даю значение в левой колонне в картинке `float: left;`, и тексту также `float: left;`, то все нормально (https://prnt.sc/fm38f1), но как поступить в правой колонне? Мне нужно чтобы текст и картинка были справа, но также чтобы эта картинка как в раз была слева от текста как в https://prnt.sc/fm38f1. Ведь сделав также - получается https://prnt.sc/fm3944 . Как поступить? Вот код:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col col-md-6" >
<img class="totallisthimg" id="totallist-left" src="/assets/img/l1.png">
<p class="totallisth" id="totallist-left"><small class="redtext">9</small><br>COUNTRIES</p>
</div>
<div class="col col-md-6">
<img class="totallisthimg" src="/assets/img/l2.png">
<p class="totallisth" id="totallist-right"><small class="redtext">9</small><br>TOTAL LISTENERS</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#totallist-left {
  font-weight: normal;
  float: left;
}
#totallist-right {
  font-weight: normal;
  float: right;
}
.totallisth {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: left;
}
.totallisthimg {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Вот скрины:

- https://prnt.sc/fm35hd
- https://prnt.sc/fm36a5

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, вам нужно центровать не картинки и текст а сами контейнеры div и все будет работать как положено. Могу предложить вариант на flex-box

```css
.container{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.totallisth {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  white-space: nowrap
}
.totallisthimg {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">

<div class="col col-md-6" >
    <img class="totallisthimg" id="totallist-left" src="blink.png">
    <p class="totallisth" id="totallist-left"><small class="redtext">9</small><br>COUNTRIES</p>
    </div>

      
  <div class="col col-md-6">
    <img class="totallisthimg" src="blink.png">
    <p class="totallisth" id="totallist-right"><small class="redtext">9</small><br>TOTAL LISTENERS</p>
    </div>
    
 </div>
```

Вот вариант без флекса если будет более 2х

```css
 .container{
  text-align: justify;
 }
 .container:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .container>*{
  display: inline-block;
   margin: 5px 0;
 }

 .totallisth {
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 10px;
   font-weight: normal;
   white-space: nowrap
 }
 .totallisthimg {
   float: left;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   margin-right: 1%;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col col-md-6" >
    <img class="totallisthimg" id="totallist-left" src="blink.png">
    <p class="totallisth" id="totallist-left"><small class="redtext">9</small><br>COUNTRIES</p>
   </div>
      
   <div class="col col-md-6">
    <img class="totallisthimg" src="blink.png">
    <p class="totallisth" id="totallist-right"><small class="redtext">9</small><br>TOTAL LISTENERS</p>
   </div>
      
<div class="col col-md-6">
    <img class="totallisthimg" src="blink.png">
    <p class="totallisth" id="totallist-right"><small class="redtext">9</small><br>TOTAL LISTENERS</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, Вам нужно во второй колонке поменять местами картинку и текст и тогда сделать float:right обоим элементам.

```css
  #totallist-left {
      font-weight: normal;
      float: left;
    }
    #totallist-right {
      font-weight: normal;
      float: right;
    }
    .totallisth {
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 23px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .totallisthimg {
      float: left;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .totallisthimg-right {
      float:right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col col-md-6" >
    <img class="totallisthimg" id="totallist-left" src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/11/504/w128h1281385326510smartphone.png">
    <p class="totallisth" id="totallist-left"><small class="redtext">9</small><br>COUNTRIES</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6">
    <p class="totallisth" id="totallist-right"><small class="redtext">9</small><br>TOTAL LISTENERS</p>
    <img class="totallisthimg totallisthimg-right" src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/11/504/w128h1281385326510smartphone.png">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Хотя это решение не подойдёт, если на маленьких экранах нужно будет чтобы и в этих колонках было по левому краю

Comment: Мне нужно картинку сделать также как и левая колонка. Но чтобы картинка прикрепилась к тексту, а текст прикрепился к правой стороне

Comment: так оно сейчас и работает - сначала текст клеится к правому краю, потом картинка, визуально - сначала картинка, потом текст, оба прижаты к правому краю (я правой картинке добавил класс totallisthimg-right)

Comment: сделал код выполняемым, чтобы увидеть, как оно будет